# can't input file into c++ program

Tags: c++

oof my brain hurts. i've been following the documentation and i still can't get this to work. string "inputString" returns nothing when the program runs. yes, the file "A3Q2.dat" is in the same directory as main.cpp. oh yeah and std namespace is a requirement for my class, otherwise i wouldn't use it. thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // new variables

    ifstream inFile;
    string fileName = "A3Q2.dat";
    string inputString;

    // Query user

    inFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ifstream::in);

    inFile >> inputString;

    cout << inputString;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the data file in the same directory as where you run the executable from?

Comment: PS: Why not check if you successfully opened the file?

Comment: Try outputting an error if `inFile.is_open()` returns false after you open the file.  Either the file isn't where your program is looking (current working directory), or the file is locked or does not have read permission.  Or it doesn't contain any non-whitespace characters ;)

Comment: This [link](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cs111/spring-2000/file-io/) may be helpful to you.

Comment: lol the default directory is buried somewhere in xcode library. for any xcode users coming across this same problem, right click on the .exe file in the "products" folder on your browser, open it and save your file to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use your code and it works well if you put the file A3Q2.dat not in the same directory of your *.exe but in another directory (also of the same project). However I suggest you to take a look on the code below to have a correct usage of exception.

```
// new variables
string fileName = "..//A3Q2.dat";
ifstream inFile(fileName);
string inputString;

try
{
    while (getline(inFile, inputString))
    {
        cout << inputString;
    }
    cin >> inputString;

    inFile.close();
}
catch (exception ex)
{
    cout << ex.what();
}

return 0;
```